# Proving $\arctan x$ has no extreme points.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

[image]

How can I prove the function $f\left(x\right) = \arctan\left(x\right)$ fulfils these requirements?
I was thinking about using supremum/infimum as I know the function is bounded by $-\frac{\pi}{2}\ ,\frac{\pi}{\ 2}$, but how do I show that they're not part of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arctan is strictly increasing, so its sup and inf are its limits in $\pm \infty$, so $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$.

But we can't have Arctan $x$ $=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$, since $\tan \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ is not defined.

Comment: How do I prove it's strictly increasing?

Comment: Arctan' $= \frac{1}{1+x^2}>0$ so it's strictly increasing.

Comment: I know. :) But I can't use it since we didn't prove it in class, therefore I must prove it if I'm to use it.. :(

Comment: Do you know $\tan$ is increasing on $[-\pi / 2, \pi / 2]$? If so, then you can write : if $x,y\in [-\pi / 2, \pi / 2]$ and $x<y$, you can write $x=\tan a$ and $y=\tan b$ with $a<b$ (if $a\geqslant b$ you would get $x\geqslant y$ by applying $\tan$).

Comment: You can also actually derive that derivative rule pretty easily: $y = \tan^{-1}(x) \to \tan(y) = x$ and then just use implicit differentiation